# How to use AxesGrid for varying size axes

Tags: matplotlib

I want to draw a quadratic Figure. It shall have 13 axes, with one being 2x2 and the others 1x1 in size (relative units). For example, it shall look like this:

```
+---+-+-+
|   +-+-+
+-+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+-+
```

I've been trying AxesGrid, but with `show_all=True`, also the top left gets filled with four axes, and if I set `show_all=False`, I don't have any axes at all on my Figure.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `gridspec` instead ([tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)).

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4)

ax_big = plt.subplot(gs[0:2, 0:2])
rest_of_axes = []
for j in range(2,4):
    for k in range(0,4):
        rest_of_axes.append(plt.subplot(gs[j,k]))

for k in range(2,4):
    for j in range(0,2):
        rest_of_axes.append(plt.subplot(gs[j,k]))
```